# Flutter : Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, I fallowed a [YouTube tutorial](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/04/30/upload-image-in-flutter-using-php/) and
When I run these code in the Android Studio, it's throwing an error message "[Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIqXA.png)" . 
My OOP knowledge is very poor and If anyone can help with this I'm glad.
Below I have mentioned some part of the codes. Full codes are available in this URL [Tutorial](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/04/30/upload-image-in-flutter-using-php/)

```
class UploadImageDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  UploadImageDemo() : super();

  final String title = "Upload Image Demo";

  @override
  UploadImageDemoState createState() => UploadImageDemoState();
}

class UploadImageDemoState extends State<UploadImageDemo> {
  //
  static final String uploadEndPoint =
      'http://localhost/flutter_test/upload_image.php';





  Widget showImage() {
    return FutureBuilder<File>(
      future: file,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            null != snapshot.data) {
          tmpFile = snapshot.data;
          base64Image = base64Encode(snapshot.data.readAsBytesSync());
          return Flexible(
            child: Image.file(
              snapshot.data,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          );
        } else if (null != snapshot.error) {
          return const Text(
            'Error Picking Image',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        } else {
          return const Text(
            'No Image Selected',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }


  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a main function in your main.dart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is explaining your issue.

> Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function

---

You must have a `main()` function in the `main.dart` file.

Please try to add it your `main.dart`

```
void main() => runApp(UploadImageDemo());
```

I suggest you start with a simple project.

Follow this guide: [Write your first Flutter app](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab#step-1-create-the-starter-flutter-app)

Comment: Thank you sir, But in the tutorial same code works on youtube. Is there any method that can set up  the android studio to start reading with the class